# screw identification:: 8-18 X 2.5 TR SC AB

Tags: appliances, hardware

Our new used stove is missing a couple of fairly important screws.  They are apparently a Whirlpool custom design (p/n [W10379120](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/part-number/w10379120/0022/664.html)), but are described as "8-18 X 2.5 TR SC AB".  I haven't found any pictures.  They're kind of pricey (~$15+ net ea, depending); so, if I can use a (modified?) regular screw, I would.  I'd also like to be sure there's not something else broken before I buy these.

So, does anyone know what the '8-18 ..' means?  Obviously, a #8, and 2.5" long.  But, does the 18-pitch imply it's self-tapping or something?  And, I have no clue about the "TR SC AB".

Thanks

Comment: They are 18-8 self tapping machine screws, type AB are fine thread type, They are stainless.  Likely a phillips drive pan head as a standard AB type.  Should sell in normal hardware stores for about .50-1.00 each.

Answer (score 1):

8-18 is number 8 size, 18 threads/inch.  The letters probably describe finish and head type (screwdriver or nut or some such).  Any chance that same screw is used somewhere else in the stove assembly & you could find it there for comparison?